# Wamp is not starting

Tags: webserver, wamp

I installed wamp in E drive on windows 7. Then for unavoidable reason I have installed new windows on that computer. again I installed wamp on same drive. But when I rum wamp it is showing me red icon.

But I need it be green icon. Please help me out.

Comment: Please add info on what is in your `Apache error log` and also your Event log ( Windows Event Viewer) look for messages from a `Source` of `Apache`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed the wamp after backing up my data and reinstall it. :)